# c++/cli Dictionary within a function argument

Tags: c++-cli

I am getting familiar with c++/cli. I am writing a function called Locate with a class called Locator. The function that takes input a dictionary of strings.

```
Dictionary<String^, array< Byte >^>^ Locate(Dictionary<String^, String^>^ imgParms)
```

I am trying to call it in the main function by doing this:

```
Locator r;

Dictionary<String^,String^> myDictionary = 
               gcnew Dictionary<String^,String^>();

r.Locate(myDictionary);
```

but I am getting this error

```
error C3073: 'System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<TKey,TValue>' : ref class does        
not have a user-defined copy constructor with
          [
              TKey=System::String ^,
              TValue=System::String ^
          ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<String^,String^> myDictionary = 
               gcnew Dictionary<String^,String^>();
```

Should be

```
Dictionary<String^,String^>^ myDictionary = 
               gcnew Dictionary<String^,String^>();
```

the `^` symbol can be thought of as a type modifier like `*` do gcnew is returning you a`x^` to type x

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. if I want to assign the return value of the fucntion to a dictionary, would I be able to do this?
    Dictionary<String^,String^>^ myResult = 
               gcnew Dictionary<String^,String^>();
    myResult=r.Locate(myDictionary);

Comment: I meant   Dictionary<String^,array< Byte >^>^ myResult = gcnew Dictionary<String^,array< Byte >^>();